# Can I draw to a Canvas from background service?

Tags: android, canvas, android-service

I have a background service that gets data from somewhere and likes to draw to a canvas.
The service creates a Canvas object and use the draw primitives on it from the service.
Does Android allow that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Background services don't interact with UI. If you're looking to show something to the user, you could instead have the service fetch the data, and notify an activity that draws. That said, I don't see why a service can't interact with a Canvas object as long as you're not displaying it. If you're just drawing on it and then writing to disk for example, I believe it should be technically possible.

Comment: Yes. It is possible to draw from background service to a Canvas. But you can't use Views and other stuff that you can layout in an activity.

Comment: How can achieve this?